# Get the src value in request parameter - Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

In puppeteer I'm trying to get the src value of an element

```
<img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Buphagus_erythrorhynchus00.jpg/220px-Buphagus_erythrorhynchus00.jpg" />
```

When I try to inspect this request with

```
page.on("request", request => {
    console.log(request.url());
}
```

The url part of the request would print out: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Buphagus_erythrorhynchus00.jpg/220px-Buphagus_erythrorhynchus00.jpg

Is there anyway I can actually also get the src value ie: *//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Buphagus_erythrorhynchus00.jpg/220px-Buphagus_erythrorhynchus00.jpg* of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string.

```
let fullURL = request.url()
console.log( fullURL.split('https:')[1] );
```

Comment: well I do want to preserve the src value, it can also be that the src value is src="http://hello.com". So I can have a solution just wouldn't be clean.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith How about this? `console.log( fullURL.split('https:')[1] || str );`